# Remove “text/x-generic header.phtml PHP script text ”

Tags: magento-1.9

I removed the Welcome Message bar by commenting out code in file: app/design/frontend/package/default/template/page/html/header.phtml

```
<!-- <div class="header-language-background">
<div class="header-language-container">
<div class="store-language-container">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?>
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this-> getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this-> getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?></p>
</div>
</div> -->
```

Instead of Welcome Message bar I now get writing: text/x-generic header.phtml PHP script text
How I do I get rid of this. I've tried altering empty.phtml in /app/design/frontend/theme/default/template /page/empty.phtml but does not work. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Under Your
/app/design/frontend/**theme**/default/template/page/html/header.phtml 

 
 To get rid of the welcome message, remove the following

```
<div class="header-language-background">
<div class="header-language-container">
    <div class="store-language-container">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?>

    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I originally did as you suggested. Now instead of Welcome message and bar I see "text/x-generic header.phtml PHP script text" in its place. How do I remove this piece of writing????

Comment: You refresh Magento cache as well as your browsers cache? I Tested on  1.9.4 and was working fine.And are other Magento core files modified as well? If not, reindex and refresh.